# Problems with Subsuperscript and Subscript Combination

Tags: plotting, style, subscript

I have a 3D figure, not important what it is, and I have the following code for the Z axis of this figure:

```
Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0] "[τ]", m, a]/
  Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][N], m, m], FontSize -> 28]
```

The problem is that it should normally look like

$$E_0[\tau]^a_m$$

However in the setting given above it looks like

$$[\tau]{E_0}^a_m$$

I was not able to take $[\tau]$ part to the front. Is it possible to do it in this setting, I mean inside:

```
Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript...
```

If not how can I do it?

Comment: The issue is the "quotes" around "[tau]".  Mma thinks you are requesting the product of `Subscript["E",0]` and the string "[\[Tau]]" rather than applying `Subscript["E",0]` to tau.  Drop the space and the quotes and it should work, as it does for E0[N].

Comment: Or, `Style["\"\<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(0\)]\)[\[Tau]]\>\"", 
 FontSize -> 28]`

Comment: In other words, try `Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][\[Tau]], m, a]/
  Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][N], m, m], FontSize -> 28]`

Comment: @evanb i tried, it doesnt work because $[]$ seems like $()$.

Comment: I see.  Here's a minimal working example: `Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0] [\[Tau]], m, a]/
     Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][N], m, m], FontSize -> 28]}]`

Comment: And a fixed version: `Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Style[Subsuperscript["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[\[Tau]]", 
      m, a]/Subsuperscript["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[N]", m,
       m], FontSize -> 28]}]`

Comment: @evanb it doesnt work again. $E$ should not be italic.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören If you want it without italic in the axes label you can use `AxesLabel -> 
 Style[Subsuperscript["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[\[Tau]]", m,
     a]/Subsuperscript["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[N]", m, m],
   SingleLetterItalics -> False]`

Comment: @Kurt thanks for the comment. I need only the E letters to be non-italic. The rest needs to be italic.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören How about `AxesLabel -> 
 Style[Subsuperscript[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[\[Tau]]", 
     SingleLetterItalics -> False], m, a]/
   Subsuperscript[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)[N]", 
     SingleLetterItalics -> False], m, m]]`

Comment: @Kurt seems good ;) thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type in a notebook the expression

```
Style[
 Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0] [τ], m, a]/
  Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][N], m, m],
 FontSize -> 28
 ]
```

the output appears as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is `StandardForm`.

When you use the same expression in a `Plot3D`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the expression prints in `TraditionalForm` which typically is viewed as more appealing.

If you want to duplicate the `StandardForm` in `Plot3D`, wrap the `Style[...` in `StandardForm`. I have also made the type `Bold` and reduced its size (completely subjective) to make it appear darker and increase the emphasis of the plot.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π},
 AxesLabel -> {
   Automatic, Automatic, 
   StandardForm[
    Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][τ], m, a]/
      Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", 0][N], m, m],
     Bold,
     FontSize -> 20]
    ]},
 ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]